# Issues in deploying deep-learning model using fast-api and tf-serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, fastapi

This is my first question on stackoverflow.
I am trying to deploy my deep-learning model using fast-api and tf-serving but when running the code it shows me **following error**:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, 3088, 3088, 3)
```

My question is that how to solve above error i.e. what code would resize any input image into (224, 224) size of image on which model is trained? Help would highly be appreciated!!

*main.py* file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import uvicorn
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins = origins,
    allow_credentials = True,
    allow_methods = ["*"],
    allow_headers = ["*"],
)

MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model("../saved_models/1")

CLASS_NAMES = ["diseased cotton leaf", "diseased cotton plant", "fresh cotton leaf", "fresh cotton plant"]

@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "Hello, I am alive"

def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))
    return image

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(
    file: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
    img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
    
    predictions = MODEL.predict(img_batch)
    
    predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
    confidence = np.max(predictions[0])
    return {
        'class': predicted_class
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host = 'localhost', port = 8000)
```

*main-tf-serving* file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import uvicorn
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import requests

app = FastAPI()

endpoint = "http://localhost:8502/v1/models/cotton-models:predict"

CLASS_NAMES = ["diseased cotton leaf", "diseased cotton plant", "fresh cotton leaf", "fresh cotton plant"]

@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "Hello, I am alive"

def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))
    return image

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(
    file: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
    img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)

    json_data = {
        "instances" : img_batch.tolist()
    }
    
    response = requests.post(endpoint, json=json_data)
    prediction= np.array(response.json()["predictions"][0])

    predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(prediction)]
    confidence = np.max(prediction)
    
    return {
        'class': predicted_class
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host = 'localhost', port = 8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trained model expects the shape of the input data to be `(None, 224, 224, 3)`, but you are passing the input of shape `(None, 3088, 3088, 3)`. Please try resizing the images. You can do it with the help of the following code. Thank you!

```
def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data))
    image=tf.image.resize(image, [224,224])
    return image
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! But it shows the error....
`module 'tensorflow._api.v2.image' has no attribute 'resize_images'`

Could you please edit the entire code snippet and send it again. It would be better...

Comment: Kindly check the modified answer above. Thank you!